# minimal polynomial of $\alpha - \beta$ from the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

If $f \in k[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha \in K$, show how to write down the minimal polynomial of $\alpha - \beta$ for $\beta \in k$.

I've been playing around with the minimal polynomial of square roots in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, for example comparing the minimal polynomials of $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}-1$... But I can't seem to find any generality.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** $f(X+\beta) \in k[x]$ has $\alpha-\beta$ as a root. Is it also irreducible/minimal?